# Can't access sharedpreferences from other activity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a fragment where I let set some SharedPreference values set.

In the fragment, everything works fine - I can get any value I want, saving, editing, deleting works fine.
Then I have an Activity, from where I want to get the value "savedValue1" - but it does not work

```
 public static final String MyPref = "MyPreference";

 static SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

//onCreateView...

sharedpreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPref,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

editor.putString("savedValue1", someString);
editor.commit();
```

I tried it with in Fragment:

```
public static String getValue(){

        return sharedpreferences.getString("savedValue1","");
    }
```

in Activity:

```
String newValue = Fragment.getValue();
```

But that doesn't work - any hint?

Comment: You should not have a `Fragment.getValue()` method. `SharedPreferences` are here to avoid that... Use the same `getSharedPreferences(MyPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` code and you shall get/set the same values inside the same preferences.

Comment: hmm I'm gonne try it... wait

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be used. From the official documentation: `For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a `Fragment.getValue()` method.

`SharedPreferences` are here to avoid that.
Use the same `getSharedPreferences("whatever", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` code and you shall get/set the same values inside the same preferences.

That is how it is supposed to be used. From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of
>   this class that all clients share.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to save and retrieve values from `SharedPreferences`

```
//To save string
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();

e.putString("savedValue1", someString);

e.commit();

//Retrieve team score
String saved_value = settings.getString("savedValue1", "");
```